# Separating strawberries form each other

Tags: strawberries

I planted a strawberry a I got a while back. It had some issues with leaves and fruits dying. I took a closer look today and turns out there are two crowns right next to each other. One crown is fruiting and the other isn't doing too good. Is it possible to separate them? or should something else be done.